# How to write the result in list instead of printing out in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm writing a predicate for finding the bigger number in pairs. If the number has no pair - it will be just added.

```
write_list([A|[]]):- write(A).
write_list([A, B|Tail]) :- ((A>B, write(A));(A<B,write(B))), nl, 
write_list([B|Tail]).
```

My problem is, I cannot figure out how to write a result in another list instead of printing the result out:

```
write_list([1,2,6,8,5], X).
X = [2,6,8,8,5].
```

Comment: Note: `[A|[]]` can simply be written `[A]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`write` only *prints* the content to the standard output, it does not "yield" it to the result list. In Prolog the only way to generate values, is through unification.

You thus need to define a predicate `maxpair/2`, *not* `write_list/1`.

The predicate thus looks like:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

maxpair([A], [A]).
maxpair([A, B|Tail], [H|T]) :-
    H #= max(A, B),
    maxpair([B|Tail], T).
```

The first clause says that the `maxpair/2` of a singleton list is that singleton list. The latter says that the `maxpair/2` for a list containing two or more lists is a list that starts with the maximum of the first two elements, and we recurse on the tail of the list.

The above can also yield a list in reverse. For example:

```
?- write_list(L, [5, 3, 2, 1]).
L = [5, 3, 2, 1] ; 
false.
?- write_list(L, [1, 4, 2, 5]).
false.
?- write_list(L, [3, 3, 5, 5]).
L = [_542, _548, _554, 5],
_542 in inf..3,
3#=max(_542, _548),
_548 in inf..3,
3#=max(_548, _554),
_554 in inf..3 ;
false.
?- write_list(L, [3, 5, 5, 4]).
L = [_1128, _1134, 5, 4],
_1128 in inf..3,
3#=max(_1128, _1134),
_1134 in inf..3 ;
false.
```

So depending on the situation it can:

1. fully reconstruct the list;
2. construct a list with some variables with intervals; or
3. proof that it is impossible to construct such a list.